# transfer data between two activity

Tags: android, android-intent, fragment

I want to send a data between two activities and based on data I show one view (I have a frameLayout and based on that data I commit a fragment for fill frameLayout). I write this code but I think it is not transferring data between the two activities! because always case 0! is executing

What is the problem??

splash:

```
private OnClickListener onClickListener=new OnClickListener(){

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Log.i("circuleProduct", "clicked");
        Intent intent;
        switch(v.getId()){
        case R.id.btnCircleProduct:
            intent=new Intent(Splash.this,MainActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            intent.putExtra("value",1 );
            break;
        case R.id.btnCircleIntroduce:
            intent=new Intent(Splash.this,MainActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            intent.putExtra("value", 2);
            break;
        case R.id.btnCircleContact:
            intent=new Intent(Splash.this,MainActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            intent.putExtra("value", 3);
            break;
        case R.id.btnCircleMore:
            intent=new Intent(Splash.this,MainActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            intent.putExtra("value", 4);
            break;
        }
    }

};
```

Activity:

```
 public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {
      @Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    FragmentManager fm=getSupportFragmentManager();
    FragmentTransaction ft=fm.beginTransaction();

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
     int value=0;
    Intent intent=getIntent();
    value=intent.getIntExtra("value", 0);

    switch(value){
    case 0:
        ft.add(R.id.frameLayout, new Introduce());
        ft.commit();
        break;
    case 1:
        ft.add(R.id.frameLayout, new Product());
        ft.commit();
    case 3:
        ft.add(R.id.frameLayout, new Contact());
        ft.commit();
    case 4:
        ft.add(R.id.frameLayout, new More());
        ft.commit();
        break;
    }
 }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DO put extra before startActivity

```
intent=new Intent(Splash.this,MainActivity.class);
intent.putExtra("value", 3);
startActivity(intent);
```

Also give break in case statement, in  switch case statement you are missing 2

```
switch(value){
case 1:
    ft.add(R.id.frameLayout, new Introduce());
    ft.commit();
    break;
case 2:
    ft.add(R.id.frameLayout, new Product());
    ft.commit();
    break;
case 3:
    ft.add(R.id.frameLayout, new Contact());
    ft.commit();
    break;
case 4:
    ft.add(R.id.frameLayout, new More());
    ft.commit();
    break;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

try to use data transfering between two activities in this way

```
 Intent i = new Intent(this, ActivityTwo.class);
  i.putExtra("Value1", 1);
  startActivity(i);
```

and in other activity after oncreate()

```
Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
int value1 = extras.getint("Value1",0);
```

see this detailed tutorial on [Android Intents](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidIntent/article.html)

Answer (score 0):

Do the `intent.putExtra("value", ...);` before you start the activity.

Answer (score 0):

Do this

```
intent.putExtra("value",1 );    
startActivity(intent);
```

instead of

```
startActivity(intent);    
intent.putExtra("value",1 );
```

Comment: yeah i changed to this but when i clicked on the contact and product buttons the program has errors. I Edit my question about this. Please read and help me.

Answer (score 0):

in main activity you have forgotten the break in switch. That means commit will be called several times. Add break to case1 and case3.
And also add the extras before calling startactivity